# Generating a zend form with dynamic data?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-session

I need to access my session and based on the session property I need to grab stuff from the database to use as options in my dropdown.

$_SESSION is:

```
[sess_name] => Array(
   [properties] => Array(
      1=> Hotel A,
      2=> Hotel B
   ),
   [selected] => 1
)
```

I need to grab Hotel A from selected, and then access all accounts under Hotel A from the database:

```
id  title                       hotel_id
------------------------------
1    Hotel A Twitter Account     1
2    Hotel B Facebook Account    2
3    Hotel A Facebook Account    1
```

I need ids 1 and 3 because my hotel_id is 1 in the context of:

```
$this->addElement(  'select', 'account', array(
  'multioptions' => $NEED_IT_HERE
));
```

Here's my query / session grabbing code:

```
$cs = new Zend_Session_Namespace( SESS_NAME );
$model = new Model_DbTable_Social;
$s = "
    SELECT social_accounts.*
    FROM social_accounts
    LEFT JOIN social_media_outlets ON social_media_outlets.id = social_accounts.property
    WHERE social_accounts.property=".(int)$cs->selectedclient;
```

I have this code in my form page, but I need to move it into my model now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So where is your problem?

Make a proper query on your database to get those accounts.

Make a proper array from the result. ( id => Title )

You can set options on already existing element:

```
$element = $form->getElement('account');
$element->setMultiOption( $option_array );
```

You can create a method in your form class which would accept DB obj, Session obj and perform the actions needed to load and set those options.

---

> model, which is in application/modules/foo/models/DbTable/Social, the model class name is Model_DbTable_Social and the module is foo. Throws Fatal error:

Your db-table class probably should be named:

```
Foo_Model_DbTable_Social
```

And application.ini should contain:

```
resources.modules[] = 
; (It is autoloader for modules)
```

> Class 'Model_DbTable_Social' when I try to invoke it in my form. Or is that way which you mention easier?

It is a good practice to ask for those resources in __construct like chelmertz said. Here is a nice talk on related subject:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

You might want to read my question on "where to connect forms to models":
[zend-framework doctrine, and mvc pattern: what kind of layer should connect data between models and forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940442)
Not too many solutions though

Comment: *Where* do I make the query to get those accounts? In the form itself? If so how do I reference the query invocation method from within the form instance? How do I actually tie in the stuff I'm doing together?

Comment: Sure, grab it from within the form, make sure to listen to the advice "ou can create a method in your form class which would accept DB obj, Session obj and perform the actions needed to load and set those options." though, so that you can inject different sources for your values. I would let the `Form_YourClass::__construct()` need to have those options (hotels as an array, for example) or else the initialization will fail.

Comment: I ported my db code to the model, which is in `application/modules/foo/models/DbTable/Social`, the model class name is `Model_DbTable_Social` and the module is `foo`. Throws Fatal error: Class 'Model_DbTable_Social' when I try to invoke it in my form. Or is that way which you mention easier?

Comment: Damn it's so much easier using django, doesn't have all these namespacing and autoloading issues. Thanks for your recommendation/answer.